# How to use two Internet Explorer windows with different IP addresses?

Tags: script, internet-explorer, browser-addons, ip-address, internet-explorer-11

I just wanted to know how to use two Internet Explorer windows with different IP addresses, I wanted to login to a browser based game to multibox using the same login but recently they restricted one login per IP so I really wanted to know how can I use two IE windows with different IP adresses(in Internet Explorer) Is there any plugins I can use or any other way to bypass this restriction? Please help me...

Comment: I don't know that how you are using the internet and how many lan ports available in your pc. However you can't use it like that way, but i can give you some idea use the proxy servers that might be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Virtualbox with another OS/Browser.  Then use a Proxy in the Virtualbox.

Or use a remote connection to another computer elsewhere to browse with Internet Explorer.